# Humans explore Mars, encounter hostile life

Tags: story-identification, movie, space-exploration, mars

This story was definitely a movie, but I've only seen it on TV.  It was probably made in the late '60s or early '70s.

The plot is a crew of explorers launched on a mission to Mars.  When they arrive they get equipped to explore (I don't recall if they used space suits or not).  One piece of equipment was a freeze ray rifle.

The first bit of hostile Martian life was a plant with tendrils that tried to grab and eat one of the astronauts.  The freeze ray handily settled that critter.

The next bit of hostile Martian life was a giant crab like creature.  It was too big for the freeze ray to stop.  So they needed to aim for smaller bits of the creature to stop it.  With skillful shots, they were able to drive the crab critter off.

The last bit of hostile Martian life was a giant amoeba like creature.  The freeze ray had no discernible effect on it.  One or two astronauts got consumed.  The rest ran back to the ship but not before one of them was touched & "infected" by the amoeba.

On the return trip the doctor/scientist figured out how to heal the "infected" astronaut.  He ran current through his arm to drive off the amoeba infection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is the film [Angry Red Planet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052564/) from 1959.  The plot description matches including the carnivorous plant, crablike alien and amoeba infection.

This [Netflix User review](http://dvd.netflix.com/Movie/The-Angry-Red-Planet/60030289?strkid=1386390974_1_0&strackid=d34af5dbc02a7d_1_srl&trkid=222336) contains many of the points you've mentioned:

> It’s true, Mars is red. Very red, thanks to something called
>   CineMagic, a filtering gimmick used to distract us from the absence
>   (or lameness) of outdoor sets. The effect is mostly tedious, but the
>   alternative is unthinkable. Mars is also very angry, probably because
>   the Earthling invaders are such disastrously bad actors. The plot:
>   After many days and much foolish dialogue, astronauts land on Mars
>   (achieved on screen by reversing stock footage of a rocket taking
>   off). More foolish dialogue as they wait for something to happen.
>   Pipe-smoking astronaut is ill at ease, feels a “controlling presence”
>   emanating from the planet. All finally venture forth to explore
>   extreme redness and native flora, some of which you will find in your
>   backyard, some of which is very badly drawn. Woman astronaut is
>   attacked by man-eating plant, but unfunny meathead astronaut zaps it
>   with the gun he will later fall in love with. Pipe-smoking astronaut
>   is attacked by the infamous and awesomely psychedelic (by virtue of
>   CineMagic) spider-crab-bat-rat monster. Later, a giant amoeba with
>   spinning googly eyes comes out of the lake and eats someone (I won’t
>   spoil it for you). Yes, there’s an oceanic lake on Mars; and yes, our
>   heroes have brought along an inflatable raft for just such an
>   occasion. The Captain is infected by the amoeba and his arm turns to
>   green goop... Do I really need to go on? You should know by now if
>   you’re cool enough to love this movie.

Comment: There couldn't be two like this.  This is the answer I was looking for, so I accepted it.  (despite admonitions to not do so...) Thanks!